# Ubuntu 14.04 CUPS driver stops spooling job after first label

Tags: printing, ubuntu-14.04, cups

I am trying to send multiple print job to printer using CUPS driver, after first job printer stops spooling remaining job.

I installed the printer from the System Settings > Printing
Add network printer
Set the printer type to Generic Raw

If I switch to Generic text only then Cups spools the entire job.

Can any one help me to understand what's problem with Queue type "Raw- Generic Text"?